# find the co-ordinate and highlight the required text in image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, nlp, computer-vision, data-science

I have the photo in which I wanted to get the co-ordinate of text and highlight the text.

[image: Image Link]

Text to highlight and get co-ordinate = '**was the age of wisdom**'
I try to get the co-ordinate by providing the first and last word but didn't get the required solution

```py
import regex as re
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'C:\\Users\\vicky\\Downloads\\image.png'


img = cv2.imread(filename)

from pytesseract import Output
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
#print(d)

n_boxes = len(d['level'])
word1 = 'was'
word2 = 'wisdom,'
for i in range(n_boxes):
    #print(d['text'][i])   ## each word 
    if(d['text'][i] == word1):
        (x, y) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i])
        #print(x,y)


    if(d['text'][i] == word2):
        (x1, y1,w1,h1) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
        #print(x1, y1, w1, h1)
        
        
        
        print(f'The coordinates of text are ({x}, {y}) and ({x1+w1}, {y1+h1})')
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x1 + w1, y1 + h1), (0, 0, 139), 5)
        break

cv2.imwrite('result2.png', img)
```

The resulted image I got

[image: Output Image]

If anybody know any other approach than this and also  want to highlight and  fill the text with pale color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to figure out the postion of the words:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('Text.png')

d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
#print(d.keys())

overlay = img.copy()
output = img.copy()
n_boxes = len(d['text'])
for i in range(18,25):
    if int(d['conf'][i]) > 60:
        (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
        # print((x, y, w, h))
        img = cv2.rectangle(overlay, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), -1)

alpha = 0.1
image_new = cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha, 0, output)

cv2.imshow('img', image_new)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @hermann12 for providing solution but I have multiple image so it want be  possible to find co-ordinate of words each time, can it  will be  possible to get highlighted text by just giving  the required words.

Comment: n_boxes is the list of words, you can easy loop this list and print position and text to find your searched words position. If you search only the word e.g. “was” it’s not identical unique.